# How "==" operator compare references? mean internal working of "==" operator

Tags: java, equals, operator-keyword

"==" or the equality operator in Java is a binary operator provided by Java programming language and used to compare primitives and objects.

"==" compares two objects based on memory reference, [so the "==" operator will return true only if the two object references it is comparing represent exactly same object, otherwise "==" will return false](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/12/difference-between-equals-method-and-equality-operator-java.html).

**My Question is how does the "==" operator works in java to compare objects**? Here we are only concerned  whether references are referencing to object or not. We are not talking about the `equals()` method.

Comment: Obvious counter question: why do you care?

Comment: Are you referring to internally?

Comment: I am assuming you know what a reference means, if you are aware what a reference is, then you have answer.

Comment: Thansk for replay, But I want to know internal working of == operator whether they works on hashcode?

Comment: No.  Two different objects can have the same hashcode, so it cannot work on the hashcode.

Comment: @fge Thansk for replay, But I want to know internal working of == operator whether they works on hashcode?

Comment: It's not using the `.hashCode()` or calling any other Java method. The JVM will compare whatever it has to identify different objects internally, maybe real memory adresses.

Comment: @neelabhsingh no they don't; for one, there is no guarantee that two "different" objectss will have a different hascode.

Comment: @fge  Guys please read question carefully before giving negative.

Comment: You may have some misconceptions about hash codes.  [This](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/04/the-3-things-you-should-know-about-hashcode/) has some good information about them.

Comment: FWIW, I didn't downvote, but whatever; my question remains unanswered

Comment: You have no idea who is giving the downvote.  Why are you spamming all of us with the same comment?  Please do not do that.

Comment: @neelabhsingh: I didn't down vote, I was trying to give you thought pointers, as christopher explained, if you know references, you can easily understand how == works.

Comment: @Nambari ,K thanks for reply, I think my question is right, I don't known why it down voted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it's actually very simple and can be illustrated using C code. In C, there are various ways of accessing a value. Using the `*` indicates a *pointer*, the `&` indicates a memory address, and neither of those defaults to the value. For example:

```
int *myValue; // A pointer to an integer value.
```

Now, Java hides this from you, but it doesn't change the fact that this is what happens.

```
Object myObject; // A pointer to an Object.
```

`==` works the way it does because the compiler will take the *actual* value of the operands; not the values they point too. When it resolves the two objects, it is left with the memory addresses and that is what it compares. This creates the illusion that it is checking if they are the same object.

**Example**

When you type..

```
int x = 5;
int y = 4;

if(x == y) { System.out.println("Do something"); }
```

the `==` is seen, and `x` and `y` are replaced with their *actual values*, so it becomes..

```
if(5 == 4)
```

Which, any compiler worth its salt can evaluate to..

```
if(false)
```

Now let's do the same thing with Objects.

```
Object object = new Object(); 
Object object2 = new Object();
```

Now we've declared two *pointers to two separate objects*. The *actual* value of `object` is a memory address, as is `object2`, so when we compare them..

```
if(object == object2)
```

this gets replaced with their memory address..

```
if(92305204950249t00 == 94205924059204t924)
// Just random values indicating memory addresses
```

And they are compared. They are different, so it becomes..

```
if(false)
```

In exactly the same way as it would with an `int`.

Comment: @christopher Thanks for replay I was looking this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let us have this code:

```
final Object o1 = new Object();
final Object o2 = o1; // legal
o1 == o2; // true
```

Any implementation of the JVM is required to return true on the third line: `o1` and `o2` are the exact same reference. Substitute `Object` for whatever other class, the above will always be true.

As to primitives, for integer types (and this includes `boolean`) this is easy; for floating point types this is not so easy; for instance, this is false:

```
Double.NaN == Double.NaN
```

which is why Java has:

```
Double.compare(Double.NaN, Double.NaN)
```

which is true.